# How to sort columns based on the first line?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to sort the columns of a very big dataset (1000 lines and 700000 columns). 
As an example, my columns are randomly arranged like: col1 col4 col3 col2, and I need to sort that.

I have been trying some commands, but no success.

example:

```
ID M2 M5 M8 M1 M3 M9 .....M7000000
Animal1 1 0 2 1 0 2 .....1
Animal2 0 1 2 0 1 1 .....0
Animal3 2 1 0 1 2 1 .....0
.
.
.
.
Animaln
```

In this example, dots means that I have a lot of columns and lines. Again, I need to sort the columns to be like:

```
ID M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 .....M7000000
Animal1 1 0 2 1 0 2 .....1
Animal2 0 1 2 0 1 1 .....0
Animal3 2 1 0 1 2 1 .....0
.
.
.
.
Animaln
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add an example with a few lines of the data set?

Comment: your expected result has only first line sorted, other values remain the same, why?

Comment: Actually, it needs to follow the columns, was a mistake of the example. sorry

Comment: Need the entire column to be sorted based on the first line.

Comment: Transpose, sort by first column, transpose back.

Comment: That would be a solution, How to transpose in Unix?

Comment: @SatoKatsura That's what I would do too, but that requires one to hold 700k * 1000 data points in memory. Not something you'd do with the standard Unix tool chest. It would have to be a Perl script or something I presume.

Comment: @Kusalananda 700k * 1000 is large, but not _huge_.  I'd try with `datamash` first, IMO Perl is unlikely to fare better.  There are of course programs that can do that for very large data, but I don't know of any free one.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843155/how-to-transpose-a-huge-txt-file-with-1-743-680-columns-and-2890-rows

Comment: @LLVerardo Please edit the output column values to match the sorted headers. If I would answer, i would test my answer and compare to your output. That could get very confusing...

Comment: I did follow @SatoKatsura suggestion using datamash and did work, and also checked as Volker Siegel suggested. It works. thanks

Answer (score 10):

With GNU [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) and GNU `sort`:

```
datamash transpose -t ' ' -H <file_in.csv | sort -V | datamash transpose -t ' ' -H >file_out.csv
```

This works fine for "reasonably small" data.  It may or may not work with your file.

**Edit:** The solutions below without transpositions should be less resource-intensive.

Comment: The [rs command](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rs&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd) might be a lighter alternative to `datamash` e.g. `rs -T < file_in.csv | sort | rs -T -C' '` (`rs` should be available as a package on Debian-based systems)

Comment: FWIW, `rs` ("reshape a data array") is available in the base systems of some BSDs.

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -pale '
   $. == 1 and
   @I = map  { $_->[1] }
        sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
        map  { [ $F[$_] =~ /^M(\d+)$/, $_ ] } 1..$#F;
   $_ = "@F[0, @I]";
' yourlargefile
```

---

1. For the first line, we numerically sort it's 2nd...last columns using their numeric portions after the digit `M` occurring at the beginning, using the well known `Schwartzian maneuver`. This affords us the indices reordered so that columns come out in numerically sorted order (M1, M2, M3, ...)
2. All that remains is to use these indices coming from `@I` to re-arrange the `@F` elements.
3. Assigning the array in a double-quoted form converts it into a string with elements space separated.
4. `-p` option to Perl enables the autoprint of `$_` contents, `-l` shall add the `newline`.

Answer (score 6):

Using the perl module Sort::Naturally

input data

```
ID M2 M5 M8 M1 M3 M9 M700000
A1 m1,2 m1,5 m1,8 m1,1 m1,3 m1,9 m1,7000000
A2 m2,2 m2,5 m2,8 m2,1 m2,3 m2,9 m2,7000000
A3 m3,2 m3,5 m3,8 m3,1 m3,3 m3,9 m3,7000000
A1000 m1000,2 m1000,5 m1000,8 m1000,1 m1000,3 m1000,9 m1000,7000000
```

```sh
perl -MSort::Naturally -lane '
  if ($. == 1) {
    @indices = (0, map  { $_->[0] }
                   sort { ncmp($a->[1], $b->[1]) }
                   map  { [$_, $F[$_]] }
                   1..$#F
               );
    $, = " ";
  }
  print @F[@indices]
' test.data
```

output

```
ID M1 M2 M3 M5 M8 M9 M700000
A1 m1,1 m1,2 m1,3 m1,5 m1,8 m1,9 m1,7000000
A2 m2,1 m2,2 m2,3 m2,5 m2,8 m2,9 m2,7000000
A3 m3,1 m3,2 m3,3 m3,5 m3,8 m3,9 m3,7000000
A1000 m1000,1 m1000,2 m1000,3 m1000,5 m1000,8 m1000,9 m1000,7000000
```

Comment: +1 for most elegant, doesn't assume too specific prefix for column names, one pass solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the [`rs` utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/rs.1.html) installed, you can do this:

```bash
rs -c' ' -T | {
    stdbuf -i0 sed "1q"
    sort -V
} | rs -C' ' -T
```

Or all on one line:

```bash
rs -c' ' -T | { stdbuf -i0 sed "1q"; sort -V ; } | rs -C' ' -T
```

- The first `rs` transposes the input data (with space-sparated fields)
- The command group:

  - `sed` reads the first line, outputs it, then quits, leaving the rest of the pipe from `rs` untouched.  `stdbuf` is required to ensure that `sed` only reads up to the first newline and no further, by turning off input buffering
  - `sort`s the remaining lines
- The second `rs` transposes the resulting stream back to its original format.

`rs` is installed by default on MacOS.  On Linux systems you may have to install it - e.g.

```bash
sudo apt install rs
```

Caveat: `stdbuf` and `sort`s `-V` option are GNU-specific so won't work on unmodified MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `awk`, you could try this:

```
NR == 1 {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        columns[substr($i, 2)] = i;
    }
    count = asorti(columns, sorted, "@ind_num_asc");
    printf("%s", $1);
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        printf(" M%s", sorted[i]);
        indx[i] = columns[sorted[i]];
    }
    print "";
    next;
}
{
    printf("%s", $1);
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        printf(" %s", $(indx[i]));
    }
    print "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
with open('in_file.csv') as infile, open('out_file.csv') as outfile:
  reader = DictReader(infile)
  writer = DictReader(outfile, fieldnames=sorted(reader.fieldnames))
  writer.writerows(reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you considered this as a good answer, but...

Why you don't use a database to solve this problem? you could import your dataset as a temporary table, and then do a

> SELECT column1, column2, ... column-n FROM my_temp_table

You could use another filters, or transformations as you need. Then, you could reformat your output as you need.

All of this tasks could be programed as a bash script, and chaining outputs using pipes.

Sometimes I have been used "pv" command to see the output progress between commands.

To import the dataset you could program an ETL using Pentaho Data Integration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could also help you.

1. First you can use transpose your file 
   (one of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash)
2. Sort first column with sort command.
3. Transpose again.

Ex:

```
$ echo "ID M2 M5 M8 M1 M3 M9 .....M7000000
Animal1 1 0 2 1 0 2 .....1
Animal2 0 1 2 0 1 1 .....0
Animal3 2 1 0 1 2 1 .....0
.
.
.
.
Animaln" | awk '
{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
            str=str" "a[i,j];
        }
        print str
    }
}' | sort -n | awk '
{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
            str=str" "a[i,j];
        }
        print str
    }
}'
ID M1 M2 M3 M5 .....M7000000 M8 M9
Animal1 1 1 0 0 .....1 2 2
Animal2 0 0 1 1 .....0 2 1
Animal3 1 2 2 1 .....0 0 1
.       
.       
.       
.       
Animaln
```